# Django: Access form_kwargs in init

Tags: python, django

I defined `form_kwargs`and I am able to access them directly in my `__init__` in forms.py. I expected to do `organizer = kwargs.pop('organizer')` etc. Can anyone explain me why it's possible that I access these kwargs directly even so they should be stored inside `form_kwargs`?

I'm currently trying to replicate this behaviour to my `class BaseReserveFormSet(BaseFormSet):` but there I can't access them without `kwargs.pop`

```
@cached_property
    def formset(self):
        ReserveFormSet = formset_factory(
            ReserveForm,
            formset=BaseReserveFormSet,
            extra=0
        )

        return ReserveFormSet(
            data=(
                self.request.POST
                if self.request.method == 'POST'
                else None
            ),
            initial=self.tickets,
            form_kwargs={
                'organizer': self.request.organizer,
                'event': self.request.event,
                'user_order_reference': self.request.session.get('order_reference'),
                'discount_code_session': self.discount_code,
            }
        )
```

**forms.py**

```
class BaseReserveFormSet(BaseFormSet):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.discount_code_session = kwargs['form_kwargs']['discount_code_session']
        self.event = kwargs['form_kwargs']['event']
        # print(kwargs.pop('discount_code_session'))  # Why does this not work?
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)    

class ReserveForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = ReservedItem
            fields = ['ticket', 'quantity']

        def __init__(self, organizer, event, user_order_reference,
                     discount_code_session, *args, **kwargs):
            self.organizer = organizer
            self.event = event
            [...]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def __init__(self, organizer, event, user_order_reference,
             discount_code_session, *args, **kwargs):
    self.organizer = organizer
    self.event = event
```

You have `organizer`, `event` and so on in the function signature, therefore you access them as `organizer` and `event`.

If you don't include them in the function signature, then you will be able to access them from kwargs.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.organizer = kwargs.pop('organizer')
    self.event = kwargs.pop('event')
```

In your `BaseReserveFormSet`, `kwargs.pop('discount_code_session')` does not work because you didn't pass `discount_code_session` to the formset, you included it in the `form_kwargs` dictionary.

If you wanted to be able to pop `discount_code_session` from `kwargs` in `BaseReserveFormSet`,

```
class BaseReserveFormSet(BaseFormSet):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.discount_code_session = kwargs['form_kwargs']['discount_code_session']
        self.event = kwargs['form_kwargs']['event']
        self.discount_code_session = kwargs.pop('discount_code_session'))
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

then you would pass it as a separate kwarg in your view. Note that the formset would no longer pass it to the form, since it would no longer be in `form_kwargs`.

```
    return ReserveFormSet(
        data=(
            self.request.POST
            if self.request.method == 'POST'
            else None
        ),
        initial=self.tickets,
        form_kwargs={
            'organizer': self.request.organizer,
            'event': self.request.event,
            'user_order_reference': self.request.session.get('order_reference'),
        },
        discount_code_session=self.discount_code,
    )
```

Comment: My problem now is just when I want to access them via `class BaseReserveFormSet(BaseFormSet):` I can only do so in my init via `self.event = kwargs['form_kwargs']['event']`. `kwargs.pop('event')`and `event` both don't work. Included or excluded of the signature.

Comment: Why should you be able to access them from `kwargs` when you passed them in `form_kwargs`. Perhaps your question would be clearer if you showed `BaseReserveFormSet`. The `form_kwargs` option is for kwargs that will be passed to the form. If you want to use them in the formset instead, then you probably shouldn't be using `form_kwargs`.

Comment: @Alasdair if you pass the argument `form_kwargs` to a formset (assuming it's a subclass of `BaseFormSet`), the actual forms in the formset will have the `form_kwargs` passed in as `kwargs` to the initialiser.

Comment: And that's where I am confused. When I print(kwargs) in the initaliser I can see form_kwargs {[...]}. However `kwargs.pop([...])` has no results.

Comment: We're talking about the `__init__()` method of the `ModelForm` `ReserveForm`, right? Not the one of the `BaseReserveFormSet`.

Comment: ReserveForm works fine. I can access everything in there with .pop() But I have issues with the `class BaseReserveFormSet(BaseFormSet)`. There I can only access via `kwargs['form_kwargs']['something']`

Comment: Correct, the initialiser of `BaseFormSet` gets exactly the same list of parameters you pass to the formset generate with the `formset_factory`.

Comment: I added BaseReserveFormSet above to my code snippet. So if I understood correctly `kwargs.pop('discount_code_session')` can't work because it doesn't has `kwargs`, but `form_kwargs`?

Comment: So basically if you override the function signature with just `**kwargs`, then your `kwargs` dictionary will have the keys `data`, `initial` and `form_kwargs` since those are the named parameters you are passing to the initialiser.

Comment: I've added an example to the question for the formset, which might make it easier to understand. You might find it helpful to print `kwargs` in the different `__init__` methods to see what they contain. Perhaps you're finding it confusing because `form_kwargs` is similar to `kwargs`. If you did `ReserveFormSet(foo={'bar': 'baz'})` you would be able to do `kwargs['foo']` in the `__init__` method, but you wouldn't be able to do `kwargs['bar']` because you passed in a single kwarg `foo`, not `bar`.

Comment: Now I got it. Thank you so much guys. Especially Alasdair for the great explanation. After I removed the function signature I could actually see the kwargs and then it became clear what form_kwargs is doing. Passing kwargs to the form. I just never saw them and was confused. Now it's clear. Thanks again!